# Diagno 1.9 modelformset_factory

Tags: python, django

Всем доброго времени! Уже весь мозг себе сломал. Необходимо фильтровать данные при вызове `modelformset_factory`. Делаю вот так:

> ```
> formset = modelformset_factory(MyModel,
> fields=['Name','User','Addresses'])
> formset=formset(queryset=MyModel.objects.get(id=1))
> self.form_class = formset
> ```

Получаю:

> TypeError: 'MyModelFormFormSet' object is not callable

Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

`form_class` должен ссылаться на форму, а не набор форм.

Comment: Form_class может ссылаться и на набор форм. Мой вопрос немного другой)

Comment: После вызова `formset = modelformset_factory(MyModel, fields=['Name','User','Addresses'])` в переменной formset у вас **класс** набора форм, а после вызова `formset=formset(queryset=MyModel.objects.get(id=1))` **экземпляр** этого класса. Атрибут CBW form_clas может содержать только класс, но не экземпляр.

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался)

Comment: Для спасибо рядом с ответом есть специальная зелёная галочка ;)